# C++ convert std::string to char

Tags: c++, string, char

I have following scenario:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  char name[25];
  char address[12];
}

Somewhere::SomeMethod(std::shared_ptr<SomeArgumentClass> args)
{
  // GetName() and GetAddress() both return std::strings
  ::MyStruct newValue = {args->GetName(), args->GetAddress()};
  // add newValue to some structure that needs to have chars
}
```

Error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'
```

I am not able to get my std::string converted to a char.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you store 2 strings instead on char[]?

Comment: You need to use `strcpy`.

Comment: The error message doesn't really fit the code you show. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Also please  read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I have to use chars because I am adding the `newValue` object to something that needs to get chars

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `strcpy` gives me `char*` but I need only `char`

Comment: `char` or `char *`? Your code says `char *` (as arrays decays to pointers to their first element) but your error message and comments says `char`.  What do you need? And remember that `std::string` have a function that can give you a `const char *`.

Comment: @T.N.: That is incorrect. `char` is one character. It is meaningless to outright convert a string of multiple characters to a single character. Which one would you pick? Did you mean an array of `char`?

Comment: Are you writing some wrapper of C API to C++ or vice versa? If not just write code which is C++ like and do not use C style code. Basically replace `char[]` with `std::string`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that is exactly what is confusing me all the time. The error message tells me I need to provide a char. But a char in that sircumstance makes no sense. I think I need a array of char. I am really really confused....

Comment: @T.N. The error is misleading but error messages can be misleading when your code makes no sense as the computer doesn't know what to make of it! Remember, it cannot determine your intentions if you don't write the correct code to represent those intentions. In this case it looks to the compiler like you're trying to convert the first std::string to the first _element_ of `name`, and the second std::string to the second element of `name`. That's how initialisers work. Yes it's confusing.

Comment: @T.N., `std::string` plays nicely with APIs taking `char*` and `const char*`. It comes with low-level functionality to get the types you need.

Comment: @chris But if `MyStruct` is a third-party C-like type then you have no choice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Ah, yeah, looking back at the comment again, *adding* this object does make it seem like it's not requiring standalone strings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have a lot of trouble understanding what the compiler is trying to tell me. I come from C# and it's a huge huge difference. I feel lost in C++, even though I thought I can program

Comment: @chris I was also looking at the global namespace qualifier on `MyStruct` which made me think it's more likely to be `SomebodyElsesStruct` :)

Comment: @T.N. C# and C++ are unrelated, different, distinct languages. It's best not to think of yourself as "coming from C#" when you're writing C++. You're "coming from" not knowing C++. And yeah it takes a lot of experience and practice to be able to quickly parse some error messages! It's pretty rewarding/fulfilling once you get there though. #wizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your terminology is incorrect. You don't want to convert to `char`, which is a single character. I realise that the error message claims you're trying to convert to `char`, but that's because your incorrect code has confused the compiler into thinking you're trying to initialise individual elements of the array `name`. Be wary of the specifics of an error message when you write the wrong code, because the compiler cannot read your mind — it can only go off of what you've written!

In reality you want to copy the characters inside your `std::string`, into the *array* of `char`, that is your member.

Like so:

```
Somewhere::SomeMethod(std::shared_ptr<SomeArgumentClass> args)
{
   const auto& name = args->GetName();
   const auto& address = args->GetAddress();

   ::MyStruct newValue;
   std::copy(std::begin(name), std::end(name), &newValue.name[0]);
   std::copy(std::begin(address), std::end(address), &newValue.address[0]);

   // add newValue to some structure that needs to have chars
}
```

But you need to add bounds checking too. To do that, roughly I might consider replacing each `std::copy` call with something like:

```
std::copy_n(
   &name[0],
   std::min(name.size(), sizeof(newValue.name)),
   &newValue.name[0]
);
```

You'll also need some null termination depending on how many characters were copied.

Generally though the salient point is that you need to actually copy those characters because there is no one-step way to do it. It stems in part from how arrays can't be assigned-to, but also from the fact that their dimensions are part of the type which makes things more complicated.

If this seems like a pain in the arse, that's because it is — ideally you would stick with `std::string` across the board because it's far superior, and was specifically introduced to make it easier to handle arrays of `char`. You can still pass a `const char*` (or `char*`!) pointing to the string's data into a C API. Of course if `::MyStruct` itself is a third-party C type, you have no choice but to do it the hard way.

Comment: If I try to add your second code, I get the following errors:

`error C2676: binary '[' : 'MyStruct' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

and

`error C2784: '_OutTy *std::copy_n(_InTy (&)[_InSize],_Diff,_OutTy (&)[_OutSize])' : could not deduce template argument for '_InTy (&)[_InSize]' from 'const char *'`

Comment: @T.N. I meant `&newValue.name[0]`, sorry

Comment: Is `std::copy_n` not already copying the strings to my destination? Can I only use `std::copy_n` then?  Also: How would the null termination look like?

Comment: @T.N. I didn't understand your first question. What do you mean "already"? You're not doing `std::copy_n` yet; that was my suggestion to start using it. As for null termination, I'm sure you can figure out how to null terminate a char array at the proper place! Some homework for you.

Comment: Ohh so you meant instead of using `std::copy`, I should use `std::copy_n` . Got it. I'll look that up myself, thanks again!

Comment: @T.N. That's right - my first (naive) suggestion was `std::copy`, then I sketched a way you can improve this (using `std::copy_n`) to get some bounds checking.

Comment: Is my understanding of null termination correct, that if I skip it, the copy function might copy too many chars into my char array since the copy function doesn't know where the end of my char array is? So I fill for example my char array with 0 and add one additional char to my char array that acts as my "end indicator"?

Comment: @T.N. Almost - the copy function is fine - but if the resulting char array is not properly terminated then (depending what you're doing with it) _using_ that char array may not work right. And yes that sounds like a good approach, or you can copy up to N-1 bytes, and set the byte after the last one written (which is min(N-1, string.size()) to null.